# Call Google Analytics tracking pixel with PHP's file_get_contents

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics

I cannot use the Google Analytics JavaScript tracking for some goals I set up in GA. Instead I want to do the same call with PHP.

It looks to me that the easiest way to do so, is to call the URL of the tracking pixel in the `<noscript />` part of the JS tracking code with PHP (e.g. `file_get_contents`)

**Does anyone have experience if I can implement it this way?**

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, for one because there is no noscript part in any recent version of the Google Analytics code.

However if you have upgraded your Google Analytics property to Google Analytics you can use the [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/) as a language independent way to make tracking calls to the Google servers (and you can make the calls to the collecting endpoint with file_get_contents if you want to. Or use CURL, or really any other method that generates http requests).

Comment: Well, it seems that my client is not using Universal Analytics yet, so the JS code that I was provided with still contains the `<noscript />` part.